# Permission in Django across native to custom table

Tags: python, django, insert, django-authentication

Django creates basic auth tables like `auth_user`, `auth_user_groups`, `auth_user_user_permissions`, etc.

I currently have (1) db with custom tables like `Tld`, etc. Tld standing for Top Level Domain.

But, django has created its own tables for permissions above. How can I tie a specific PK in `auth_user` to my `Tld` table?

I know, I know a **FK->PK** relationship, but this doesn't come out of the box.

Basically, I want to check if a user has a tld currently (which should just be a JOIN) on the two tables, but as the db currently stands `<any-django-out-of-box-auth>` table doesn't know about any custom table I've made.

How do I get this process working, for example, I have a view that creates new records for Tlds:

```
def Scan(request):
    form = SubmitDomain(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
            domainNmCleaned = form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
            form.save() #save cleaned data to the db from dictionary
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/S/?domainNm=' + domainNmCleaned)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')
    else:
        form = SubmitDomain()

    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
        'form' : form 
    })
```

How do I get it to also insert the currently logged in `User` id in another table called `Tld__User`?
So that, when I join `Tld` with the system created `Auth_User` table I can see if a user has any Tld?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this after some further research:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends